# dojo declare constructor and this object and safemixin

Tags: javascript, constructor, dojo, declare

I am reading an application code that written dojo.

```
define(["dojo/ready", "dojo/_base/declare"], function(ready, declare) {
  return declare("application.main", null, {
    constructor: function(options) {
        var _self = this;
        this.options = {};
        declare.safeMixin(_self.options, options);

    }
    addReportInAppButton: function() {
        var _self = this;
        if (_self.options.appName) {
 }});
```

I confused about some points.

1. in constructor function and addReportInAppButton used **this** keyword and assigned to _self property.
2. Declare.safeMixin(_self.opt.ons, options)

options is an array like this **{ "appName":"xyz", "appId":"1141"}**

I noticed that assigned this.options is using in addReportInAppButton function like this _self.oprions.appName,

How does this work? and is declare.safeMixin copiying object to this.options?

Answer (score 0):

1. In both functions, _self is equal to this and could be safely removed. Most likely this is just a convention, possibly from having to declare _self when wanting to access it in eg. a callback:

   ```
   var _self = this; 
   on(someButton, 'click', function() {
       this.foo() // this !== _self
       _self.foo() // used to access properties of the original context
   });
   ```
2. Yes, safeMixin copies all of options' properties into _self.options. safeMixin also ensures that if you copy a function, you will be able to call **this.inherited** on it and it will work as expected.

You could use the mixin() function in dojo/_base/lang, but that would throw an error if you tried to call this.inherited on a function.

The [docs on dojo/_base/declare](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/_base/declare.html#id11) have some more elaborate examples for safeMixin